# C Shell detemined the file

Tags: shell-script

I'm very new to C Shell. I'm trying to read a file from the command line, and determine whether it's a zip file, a .txt, a symbolic link, a pipe, or whatever ("unknown").

Then I'd like to execute a few instructions depending on the type. For instance, if it's a .txt file, print information about it ("it's a text file") and give its size.

**How do you read from Command line instead of -ls? I am very confused**

Here is what I what got so far: Whenever I run it i got this

```
cshell.sh: Command not found
```

```
#!/bin/tcsh

#copying the out of ls -l command to a file
ls -l > /tmp/tmp.tmp

#initilizing values
sum=0
dir=0
file=0
link=0

#reading the file
while read line
do 
    #getting the first character of each line to check the type of file     
    read -n 1 c <<< $line

    #checking if the file is a directory or not
    if [ $c == "d" ] 
    then
        ((dir++))
        echo "[DIR] ${line}/" | cut -d" " --fields="1 9" >> /tmp/dir.tmp

    elif [ $c == "-" ] #true if the file is a regular file
    then
        ((file++))
        echo $line | cut -d" " -f8 >> /tmp/file.tmp

    elif [ $c == "l" ]  #true if the file is a symbolic link
    then
        ((link++))
    fi

    size=$( echo $line | cut -d" " -f5 ) #getting the size of the file
    sum=$(( sum+size )) #adding the size of all the files 
done < /tmp/tmp.tmp

cat /tmp/file.tmp #output the name of all the files
cat /tmp/dir.tmp #output the name of all the directory

echo "Total regular files = $file"
echo "Total directories = $dir"
echo "Total symbolic links = $link"
echo "Total size of regular file = $size"

#removing the temporary files
rm /tmp/file.tmp
rm /tmp/dir.tmp
rm /tmp/tmp.tmp
```

Comment: What command are you actually running? Please include the command in your question.

Comment: Note that the script you have, which is from http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Chapter_5_answers , is for `bash`, not `tcsh`. You will have to change a few lines there, because the shells have different statement formats.

Comment: To anyone looking for this functionality today, check out the `file` program / command. It may save you some time writing your own script. I know that is available on Debian systems via `apt`, and I believe it may even come out-of-the-box on many distros, but I am not sure about this. Regardless, [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) is the man-page(1) and [here](http://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/) is a link to the source, in case it cannot be obtained via package manager in your system.

Answer (score 2):

You're having the command not found because you don't have `cshell.sh` configured for the commandline to find it.

There are two things you need to do to have it found as an a command.  You need to have it marked as an execution file with something like:

```
$ chmod go+x cshell.sh
```

You also need to either have it in your execute path or run it by a pathname.  If you are in the directory with the script you can run it with:

```
$ ./cshell.sh
```

Also you can check your execution path with:

```
$ echo $PATH
```